# Why doesn't <br> work in php? Below code doesn't break the sentences

Tags: php

```
<?php echo "This is my first php file";
echo "<br>";
echo "This is my first php file ";

echo "First name"   .   "second name";
echo "<br>";

echo 6;
?>
```

Comment: It should work. So there's something else wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `\n` or `\r\n` to see new lines in PHP output. `<br>` is for HTML newlines

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "This is my first php file";
  ?>

  <br> <!-- only HTML -->

<?php
  echo "This is my first php file ";

  echo "First name"   .   "second name";
   ?>
 
 <br> <!-- only HTML -->

 <?php

  echo 6;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need use `PHP_EOL` instead of `br`